# Show that it is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ a finite Borel measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $B_x$ an open disc with center $x$ and radius $1$.

Show that the function $f(x)=\mu (B_x)$ is measurable.

Could you give me some hints how I could do that??

Answer (score 2):

It's more than measurable, it's lower semicontinuous: Pick a sequence $x_k\to x$, then $1_{B_{x}}\leq \liminf_k 1_{B_{x_k}}$. Therefore by Fatou's lemma
$$
f(x)=\int_{B_x} d\mu \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \liminf_k 1_{B_{x_k}} d\mu \leq \liminf_k \int_{B_{x_k}} d\mu =\liminf_k f(x_k).
$$

Comment: Could you explain to me how we get the inequality $$1_{B_x} \leq \lim inf_k 1_{B_{x_k}}$$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar: If $y\in B_x$ then whenever we have $|x-x_k|<1-|x-y|$, we'll get $y\in B_{x_k}$. Arguing similarly if $y\notin \bar{B}_x$ we conclude that if $y\notin \partial B_x$ then $1_{B_{x_k}}(y)\to 1_{B_x}(y)$. But since, if $y\in \partial B_x$, $1_{B_x}(y)=0\leq 1_{B_{x_k}}(y)$, so the inequality follows.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?? And also when we have shown that $f(x) \leq \lim inf_k f(x_k)$ why does this mean that $f$ is semicontinuous??

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding? As for your other question see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity).

Comment: Instead of showing that $f$ is semicontinuous, could we have also showed that $f$ is continuous?? Is the following correct?? When $x \rightarrow y$ we have that $f(x)-f(y) \rightarrow 0$ since the measure of the difference is the measure of the part of the balls that don't intersect.

Comment: @MaryStar: No. In general $f$ will not be continuous unless you know that $\mu(\partial B_x)=0$ for every $x$. Then it just becomes an application of the DCT.

Comment: $f(x)-f(y)=\mu (B_x \setminus B_y)$. When $x\rightarrow y$ why isn't $\mu (B_x \setminus B_y)=0$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar: Think of the case in $\mathbb{R}$. Set $\mu=\delta_0$ Dirac's delta. Now put $x=-1$, $x_k=-1+1/k$. Then $x_k\to x$ but $\mu(B_x)=0$ and $\mu(B_{x_k})=1$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try $d=1$ first. Fubini's theorem might help.